# Why android does not let me update my UI in my own thread

Tags: android

I understand I need to put the code for long processing time to my own thread, not the UI thread. My question is why in my own thread, android does not let me update the UI, e.g. update the text of my TextView in UI?

Thank you.

Comment: Related  code post my help in finding what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a design tradeoff, the Android UI toolkit is not thread-safe. So you cannot update the UI from any thread other than your UI thread. The platform provides a number of ways (such as `runOnUIThread`) to make it painless to dispatch tasks to the UI thread so that it can update the UI.